# Drupal views filtering content by node id

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-views

I have the following scenario:

I have a content type called 'Product' in which there are the default input fields and a number of custom input fields that have been created using CCK.

When a new product is created, all of the data entered is posted as a node (as normal).

Part of the problem is that I don't want the values from the custom input fields to be within the node content. Therefore, my thinking was to hide the display of these fields. I could then create  a block of the custom input fields using views.

Is it possible within views to set up some filtering that will only display the values of the custom input fields on the node from which it was originally created? For example if the product I created had a node id of 1, is it possible to filter the view to display the values of the custom input fields that were created from node id of 1 and then display these values as a block on node id 1?

This might sound a confusing approach but I am keen to separate some of the data entered into the Product content type from the main node content, mainly for styling reasons.

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah worked it out. It's always an easy solution isn't it?

In the Arguments section of the view, add Node: Node ID. Select the action of 'Provide default argument' and then select 'Node ID from URL' from the 'Default argument type:'.

This will then just display the values of the custom input fields that was created on a particular node.